# É possível ter sob o mesmo domínio mais de uma WEB-API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Boa tarde!
Sou novo na área de desenvolvimento e estou caminhando na área de aplicações Web. Eu desenvolvi uma web-api que já se encontra hospedada e em funcionamento. Entretanto, estou desenvolvendo outro projeto e gostaria de utilizar o mesmo domínio. É possível ? Ilustrando a situação:

O que já está em funcionamento:
wwww.meudominio.com.br/api1/controller/funcao

O que pretendo:
www.meudominio.com.br/api2/controller/funcao

Comment: Sim, existem várias maneira de se fazer isso. Você consegue sigmentar por "pastas", por subdominios e por portas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim. Pode ver aqui como fazer:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35865437/multiple-asp-net-web-api-on-the-same-iis
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36475947/asp-net-web-api-multiple-applications-under-same-host-name

Na prática basta criar novas pastas/sites/portas no IIS e fazer o deploy para o sitio certo. No visual studio pode fazer publish para o server/sitename pretendido.

No IIS faça algo deste gênero:
[image: Configuração IIS]

No Visual Studio pode usar o Publish em conformidade com as definições do Servidor IIS:
[image: Publish VS]

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/214052)

Comment: @LeAndrade, tem razão. Editei agora a minha resposta (ainda sou novo nas regras do stackOverflow).